Partition evolution by PyIceberg
I am trying to put a dataframe to Minio-iceber with partition evolution. But it throw this error:
ValueError: Could not find in old schema: 1000: datetime_day: day(15)

I am trying to put a dataframe to Minio-iceber with partition evolution.
This my code:
schema = Schema(
        NestedField(field_id=1, name="id", field_type=IntegerType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=2, name="uid", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=3, name="password", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=4, name="first_name", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=5, name="last_name", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=6, name="username", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=7, name="email", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=8, name="avatar", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=9, name="gender", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=10, name="phone_number", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=11, name="social_insurance_number", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=12, name="date_of_birth", field_type=TimestampType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=13, name="credit_card_cc_number", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=14, name="row_id", field_type=StringType(), required=True),
        NestedField(field_id=15, name="datetime_day", field_type=StringType(), required=True)
    )

    partition_spec = PartitionSpec(
        PartitionField(
            source_id=15, field_id=1000, transform=DayTransform(), name="datetime_day"
        )
    )

    sort_order = SortOrder(SortField(source_id=1, transform=IdentityTransform()))
    

    hive_catalog = load_catalog(
        "hive",  
        **{
            "uri": "thrift://hive-metastore:9083",
            "s3.endpoint": "http://minio:9000",
            "s3.access-key-id": "my-ak",
            "s3.secret-access-key": "my-sak"
        }
    )

    arrow_df = pa.Table.from_pandas(wh_table['dim_user_info'])
    if not hive_catalog.table_exists("lakehouse_dw1.dim_user_info"):
        table = hive_catalog.create_table(
            "lakehouse_dw1.dim_user_info",
            schema=arrow_df.schema,
            partition_spec=partition_spec,
            sort_order=sort_order
        )
    else:
        table = hive_catalog.load_table("lakehouse_dw1.dim_user_info")
        table.append(arrow_df)**your text**

I preferred to this Document

It looks like your field_id is wrong. You need to use field_id=15 instead of 1000. Also, check if the field type String will work with the DayTransform

Have you find solution ?
I've got the same error by using MinIO and PyArrow.

Sorry for this late. I've resolved the issue. There are two key points to ensure:

The data types in the schema must match those in PyArrow.
The default value for the "required" field is set to False.

